# UserControl with an xml resource file, how does it work?

Tags: c#, xml, user-controls, resources

I created a UserControl that uses an xml file as a resource to get data from. The file's build action is set to "none" and copy is set to "do not copy". I can see the xml file in the UserControl project folder.

Now when i reference the UserControl's dll in another project and use it - it works great, i just want to understand how it works. I don't see the xml file anywhere in the using project directory. I even tried copying the \debug\bin folder to another location and ran the .exe and everything's ok, how does it work exactly? Where is the xml file located when the UserControl is being used in another project?

Comment: Try searching in your project folder..  What's your problem and what you've tried??

Comment: I don't have any problem but i wish to understand how what i did works. I edited my post to be more clear.

Comment: Dll comprises of all the files you need!  Try IL diassembler and decompile your dll.  Hope that helps you!

Comment: @DirtyDeveloper Thanks! now i get it..

Comment: Hope you liked the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dll comprises of all the files you need!  Try IL diassembler and decompile your dll.  Hope that helps you!